# android-O : app crash with webview

Tags: android, webview, android-8.0-oreo

I have simply put a `WebView` in layout.
When I run the project in Android-O preview emulator, it gives below error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mvvmrecyclerview, PID: 3527
java.lang.SecurityException: Signature check failed for com.example.mvvmrecyclerview
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1915)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1861)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzv$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source:41)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzf$zzc.zzxQ(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzf$zzf.run(Unknown Source:0)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabx.run(Unknown Source:7)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

If you want to generate this error, simply create a new project, Put webview in your layout and try to run the project in Android O emulator.

can anyone help me with this. Thanks.

**PS:** Android Studio 2.4 Preview 3

Comment: have you checked permission has been granted for INTERNET??

Comment: @Nazimch As I said, I have just put webview in layout. and I have code nothing else than that. Answer has been given. You might want to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36581808). Some sketchy workarounds are included in the issue comments. In general, you may need to hold off on O work until ODP2 rolls out (probably around Google I|O in mid-May).

Comment: Thank you sir for pointing out the issue. I am not targeting Android-O as of now.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've face with one similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271777/webview-crash-in-android-o, is this know issue too?

Comment: @user2910110: I have no idea. You would need to try to look at up in either the Android or Chromium issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

It may look like known issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=267699

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36581808

Comment: Thanks Pranay. Lets wait for new release :D